# php redirect with a session assignment prior to it

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

As you already know, any exchange with the server cauase `header()` to become unstable. For my project, in login controller, I see if the user has inserted true user/pass, I set a session `$_SESSION['email']` and then redirect it to user_home controller. This causes problem when the website is hosted. What do I mean by problem? I simply mean it does nothing, neither error nor anything else. What should I do?

Here is an example of code written in CodeIgniter as login controller. Pay a close attention to the redirection and prior to that session assignment.

```
$data['email'] = $this->input->post("email");
$data['password'] = $this->input->post("password");

echo ($login_result = $this->authentication->login($data));

if($login_result == -1)
{                   
    $this->session->set_flashdata("login-result", FAILED);
    redirect(base_url("access/login")); 
}
else if($login_result != -1)
{                                       
    if($login_result['status']  == 0) // not activated
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata("login-result", NOACT); // for constant use please check the appropriate files
        redirect(base_url("access/login")); 
    }
    else if($login_result['status']  == 1) // activated
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata("email", input("email"));
        redirect(base_url("panel/home"));   
    }
    else if($login_result['status']  == 2) // banned
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata("login-result", BANNED);// for constant use please check the appropriate files
        redirect(base_url("access/login")); 
    }                       
}
```

Comment: There is, without a doubt, an error. that error is, `error: cannot set headers after data has been sent`.

Comment: Have you tried your code without using echo at the top?

Answer (score 0):

You redirect function is using header like:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

[header()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

```
$data['email'] = $this->input->post("email");
$data['password'] = $this->input->post("password");

$login_result = $this->authentication->login($data);

if($login_result == -1)
{                   
    $this->session->set_flashdata("login-result", FAILED);
    redirect(base_url("access/login")); 
}
else if($login_result != -1)
{                                       
    if($login_result['status']  == 0) // not activated
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata("login-result", NOACT); // for constant use please check the appropriate files
        redirect(base_url("access/login")); 
    }
    else if($login_result['status']  == 1) // activated
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata("email", input("email"));
        redirect(base_url("panel/home"));   
    }
    else if($login_result['status']  == 2) // banned
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata("login-result", BANNED);// for constant use please check the appropriate files
        redirect(base_url("access/login")); 
    }                       
}

echo $login_result;
```

Comment: This will not do. You moved setting the value of $login_result below the code block that checks its value...

Comment: You make an output, than redirection - i think it's pointless

Comment: so what should I for setting sessions in cases like above that I also need to redirect?

Comment: Writing standard output at any point when redirecting is pointless. But your code is logically broken.

Answer (score 0):

A fix to Dmitriy's suggestion (and probably the right answer) would be:

```
$data['email'] = $this->input->post("email");
$data['password'] = $this->input->post("password");

$login_result = $this->authentication->login($data);
if($login_result == -1)
{                   
    $this->session->set_flashdata("login-result", FAILED);
    redirect(base_url("access/login")); 
}
else if($login_result != -1)
{                                       
    if($login_result['status']  == 0) // not activated
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata("login-result", NOACT); // for constant use please check the appropriate files
        redirect(base_url("access/login")); 
    }
    else if($login_result['status']  == 1) // activated
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata("email", input("email"));
        redirect(base_url("panel/home"));   
    }
    else if($login_result['status']  == 2) // banned
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata("login-result", BANNED);// for constant use please check the appropriate files
        redirect(base_url("access/login")); 
    }                       
}

// echo ($login_result = $this->authentication->login($data));
```